# Error in checkout and checkin files in TFS programatically despite having permissions

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk

I want to programatically connect to TFS and be able to checkout and checkin the files. For that purpose, I am using the following code (some private information omitted), however, I get the "not having sufficient permissions error", I have checked with the administrator and he has given me both read and write permissions, can anyone please help me. Here's the code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;

namespace CodeGeneration
{
    public class CheckInTFS
    {
        public static void ProcessFile()
        {
            var tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://tfs"));
            var versionControlServer = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>(); 
            var workspace = versionControlServer.GetWorkspace(@"D:\Test");

            #region Checkout File

            var file = @"D:\EnumGeneration.cs";
            workspace.PendEdit(file);
            var pendingChange = workspace.GetPendingChanges();

            #endregion

            #region Checkin File

            workspace.CheckIn(pendingChange, "Test Comment!");
            #endregion
        }
    }
}
```

The error which I receive is this:

[image]

Also, I have looked at the permissions from [This MS Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and I have GENERIC_READ and GENERIC_WRITE permissions.

Comment: I do have GENERIC_READ and GENERIC_Write permissions, which other permissions do I need? I checked the permissions from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: are you running visual studio as Administrator ?

Comment: Sometimes its better to do the trial & error especially with Permissions. Try having all permissions & see if this error shows up. If it works try removing a bunch of permissions & do it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this sample, try with this and let me know if you still have persmisson problems when adapting and running this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client; 
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client;

namespace TfsApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            // Connect to Team Foundation Server
            //     Server is the name of the server that is running the application tier for Team Foundation.
            //     Port is the port that Team Foundation uses. The default port is 8080.
            //     VDir is the virtual path to the Team Foundation application. The default path is tfs.
            Uri tfsUri = (args.Length < 1) ? 
                new Uri("http://Server:Port/VDir") : new Uri(args[0]);

            TfsConfigurationServer configurationServer =
                TfsConfigurationServerFactory.GetConfigurationServer(tfsUri);

            // Get the catalog of team project collections
            ReadOnlyCollection<CatalogNode> collectionNodes = configurationServer.CatalogNode.QueryChildren(
                new[] { CatalogResourceTypes.ProjectCollection },
                false, CatalogQueryOptions.None);

            // List the team project collections
            foreach (CatalogNode collectionNode in collectionNodes)
            {
                // Use the InstanceId property to get the team project collection
                Guid collectionId = new Guid(collectionNode.Resource.Properties["InstanceId"]);
                TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = configurationServer.GetTeamProjectCollection(collectionId);

                // Print the name of the team project collection
                Console.WriteLine("Collection: " + teamProjectCollection.Name);

                // Get a catalog of team projects for the collection
                ReadOnlyCollection<CatalogNode> projectNodes = collectionNode.QueryChildren(
                    new[] { CatalogResourceTypes.TeamProject },
                    false, CatalogQueryOptions.None);

                // List the team projects in the collection
                foreach (CatalogNode projectNode in projectNodes)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" Team Project: " + projectNode.Resource.DisplayName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

taken from here

**http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb286958.aspx**

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet did the trick:

```
var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(TFS_SERVER));
var workspaceInfo = Workstation.Current.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo(FULL_FILE_PATH);
var workspace = workspaceInfo.GetWorkspace(tfs);
```